# Running RSpec - Factory Girl locks up and doesn't run - Rails Sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, sandbox

Just wanted to post a quick thing I found about Factory Girl for others who are new to using it like myself.  The use-case for this solution is likely limited, but it's worth posting.

I was running rspec for a controller in one of projects, and for some reason the thing wouldn't run for some tests.  Not all of them, just some.  I tried deleting everything in that test file and running it - it successfully found 0 examples, so clearly the file was being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being simple: I had a rails console in test environment, sandbox environment running (you can start this with "rails c test" and add a -s flag for sandbox mode, for your own reference). When you have Factory Girl make changes to a sandbox environment, running Factory Girl anywhere else in your app before killing the sandbox session results in it locking up.

For me it was running in the background because I previously had it running and stopped it using ctrl + z.  The solution is simply kill the rails console process using

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

and with the pid (ex. 1234)

```
sudo kill -9 1234
```

I can assume a similar problem might happen regardless of whether or not you're using Factory Girl, and is more of a problem when you make changes to the sandbox, but this problem.

EDIT: I have confirmed this is a FactoryGirl problem only - creating entries through other means in the rails console (for example), even if a rails sandbox is running with Factory Girl changes, does not cause issues.  Basically, this issue will only come up if you run Factory Girl in one rails c test sandbox, and then try running Factory Girl elsewhere to my knowledge.